# How can I hide the store switcher

Tags: magento2

I want to hide the store switcher of the top of my page.
I'm using Magento 2.1.9
How can I do this?
[image]

Comment: Are you talking about default theme or any purchased template

Comment: I updated the post. I'm using a purchased template called "Everything". So I guess I have to ask the template creator?

Comment: You can use this solution add this line `<referenceBlock name="store_language" remove="true"/>` in `/app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under

```
/public_html/app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/web/css/source
```

you create a file called:`_extend.less`

add this code in it:

```
.switcher select
{
display:none
}
```

Clear your cache afterwards and it should works.
If it doesn't, maybe the CSS Selector is wrong, so you have to find the correct one.

The effect of this addition is that the Language switcher will not be rendered, it will still get loaded by your Magento.

Comment: Easiest tweak ! Good

Comment: Not a good solution as it will just hide it using CSS. Why render unnecessary HTML elements on page when those are not used. Better remove it using layout updates.

Comment: Easy tweak, bad solution.

Answer (score 6):

For Magento 2, you can hide the store switcher by removing the **store_switcher** block. 
To remove the store_switcher block, extend the Magento_Theme default.xml file by creating the default.xml in your theme:
app/design/frontend/your_vendor_name/your_theme_name/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

In the default.xml file:

```
<body>    
   <referenceBlock name="store_switcher" remove="true"/>
</body>
```

Then clear cache: `bin/magento cache:clean`

Answer (score 0):

For Magento 2 you can disable it via your customer theme folder. In your file app/design/frontend///Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml you can add the line  between the tag

```
...
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="store_switcher" remove="true"/>
...
```

Flush the cache afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

For me, using the Ultimo theme for Magento 2, after I added a new Store View this dropdown appeared on the frontend with an ID of "switcher-language".
To remove it, I made the following changes to this file:

- app/design/frontend/THEME/CHILD/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

1. Added to bottom:
   `<referenceBlock name="store_language" remove="true"/>`
2. Commented out this section: `<block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_language.mobile" template="switch/languages.phtml"> <arguments><argument name="id_modifier" xsi:type="string">mobile</argument?</arguments></block>`