# Magento 2 Remove language switcher

Tags: magento2, language-switcher, remove-block

I am trying to remove language switcher and to do this I have added a line in:

> app/design/frontend/MyPackage/MyTheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

I just add a line in `<body>`

```
<referenceBlock name="store_language" remove="true"/>
```

Executed deployment script, but I am still seeing `Magento_Store/templates/switch/languages.phtml` in profiler files list

Any idea what should do to resolve it?

Comment: Is this now display in header or not?you are doing correct way please clear all cache manually and again try.

Comment: Actually I havn't called it in header, but file is appearing in profiler. Yes I did clear cache manually

Comment: you have run again `deploy` command?

Comment: @RakeshDonga yes, ran it multiple times, but it is still appearing on profiler list

Comment: You can do it CSS way https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/205694/how-can-i-hide-the-store-switcher

Comment: which theme are you using?

Comment: I am using custom theme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `<referenceBlock name="store_language" remove="true"/>` should work, try to clean the cache :

   `php bin/magento c:c && php bin/magento c:f`.
2. If it doesn't work, try to enable the **template and block path hints** : `Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug` and look the block name of the **store switcher**. if there no block, that means that the switcher has beed added in a phtml, in this case you have to do it in directly in that phtml.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) But it didn't work for me :(... Cleared cache as you said. enabled template hint, there is no block found with the name **switcher** found, but still profiler showing `..Magento_Store/templates/switch/languages.phtml` :(

Comment: It's strange, look in your theme if you have `Magento_Store/templates/switch/languages.phtml` ?

Comment: Yes it is in my theme

Comment: ok, try to update it, and look if you see the changes in storeswitcher

Comment: Thank you for the point of view that you have given, I have checked in DOM, file is not loading in DOM, but only profiler is showing it. I think it is not a problem if it is not showing in DOM

Comment: You're welcome, good luck

Answer (score 0):

Add below code default.xml file which is located in layout folder

[image]

Run command: php bin/magento c:c && php bin/magento c:f to clean cache

Answer (score 0):

You can override template Magento_Store\templates\switch\languages.phtml with blank content,
That`s shoud work..tested